# Rails / Devise: Namespaced RegistrationsController fetching non-namespaced views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a Rails 4 / Devise 3 app. I have a base set of routes and view files that is pretty standard. I then have a namespaced `portals` set of views and routes that are only hit when a user access the site through a subdomain.

How do I tell me namespaced `Portals::RegistrationsController` to get the Devise views from `app/views/portals/devise` rather than `app/views/devise`?

Here is my controller:

```
class Portals::RegistrationsController < RegistrationsController
    layout 'portals/layouts/application'
    append_view_path 'portals'

    def create
        @portal = Portal.friendly.find(request.subdomain)
        super
    end

    def edit
        @portal = Portal.friendly.find(request.subdomain)
        super
    end

    def update
    end
end
```

I tried using `append_view_path 'portals'` but that seemed to have no effect. All my other non-devise controllers grab the right view files by default.

Comment: Try this: `prepend_view_path 'app/views/portals'` so this should look the views in path: `app/views/portals/devise`

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with `prepend_view_path` regardless of what I passed as the argument. I managed to skirt the problem by adding some conditionals to my view, but that's far from a clean solution.